# Codeigniter permitted_uri_chars clean from value of url

Tags: php, codeigniter

i wanna change url parameters values if has special characters from url. For this i customised filter_uri method in MY_URI core.

```
class MY_URI extends CI_URI {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}


/**
 * Filter URI
 *
 * Filters segments for malicious characters.
 *
 * @param   string  $str
 * @return  void
 */
public function filter_uri(&$str)
{

        if ( ! empty($str) && ! empty($this->_permitted_uri_chars) && ! preg_match('/^['.$this->_permitted_uri_chars.']+$/i'.(UTF8_ENABLED ? 'u' : ''), $str))
        {
         // What i must write here ?
        }
}
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate your question more?

Comment: @JoshulSharma at codeigniter has some not acceptable characters. this function ignore this characters. i wanna delete that characters from url values.

Comment: if you want to restrict or allow special characters in URI then you can do that in config.php file in application/config folder. Search for : $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-'; and add/remove characters as you wish.

Comment: @JoshulSharma thank you. i mean, i can ignore this characters. its ok. But i wanna at url can be "myurl/metin+erbek" for example. i ignored + character already. but when codeigniter checking this url, passing from this function. when passing i want make this metin+erbek to metin-erbek for example. at url still can be metin+erbek.

Comment: This url "myurl/metin+erbek", are you creating this? i mean like this:  <?php echo anchor("myurl/".$your_name);?>, if yes then i can think of a solution that may work.